# Finding average function value based on data points.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, average

Let's say I have 200 data points $(x,y)$. I know the step size for the input $x$ is $h$.  To find the approximated average function value $A$ of some unknown function $ x \mapsto y$,  I believe I could use a trapezoid rule like:

```
I  = 0;
for k = 1:199

    I = I + h * ( y(k) + y(k+1) ) * (1/2);

end  

A = 1/(x(end) - x(begin)) * I;
return A;
```

But I was just thinking, can't I just take the mean of the $y$-vector, to get the same result?

Comment: Notice that $y_1$ and $y_{200}$ have different weights in the trapezoid rule comparing to the arithmetic mean.

Comment: @user251257 Ok, I see what you're saying. For the trapezoid rule $y_1$ and $y_{200}$ have weight $1/400$ while the inner terms have weight $1/200$. I'm guessing the trapezoid rule is more accurate for approximating continuous functions, is that true? Or how would I go about analyzing such a thing?

Comment: see Wikipedia for error analysis.